# Git how to rebase commits on master after pulling?

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-squash

I checked out a branch:
`git checkout -b myBranch`

Made some commits:

`git commit -m 'msg'`

`git commit -m 'msg2'`

Then I pulled from master. Now I have many staged files in which I did no work. How can I squash all the changes from master and move my commits on top?

Comment: You have many staged files after pulling master? Check them, perhaps you didn't finish a commit you wanted to?  --- the answer to your technical question normally is `git rebase master` however I don't understand the "squash" part so I have excluded it.

Comment: Indeed I have many staged files after pulling from master.

Comment: `git rebase master
error: cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.`


Can't rebase, and if I commit, I am committing all the files from master

Comment: Try `git rebase --autostash master`.

Comment: and then commit?

Comment: commit, stash or reset - this is entirely up to you. do whatever suits you best, it's your repository.

Comment: `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. That second Git command has *stalled out in the middle*. You must figure out what you want to do with that, and either complete the command, or abort it entirely and do something different. (This is why I recommend that newbies avoid `git pull` entirely. Avoiding it won't help you with the second command, but it will at least let you know that there *is* a second command, and that that's the one that has not yet succeeded.)